# php integer increment throws memory erro

Tags: php, for-loop, integer

I am facing a weird problem. I am trying to create a generic passenger list that populates itself. It decides on gender, name and male / female. Also if a family member will be added. This list has a counter (`$person`) that works with a **for** function. So the first person on the list is 1, the second is a 2, if the 3rd is a family member of the second, the `$person` integer gets a ++. However, this `$person++` creates two out of three times a memory issue and the page won't be loaded; fatal memory error *(Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 266338360 bytes))*

How can this be solved?

```
function insertPax($class, $pax, $nat) {

for($person = 1; ; $person++) {
    
    $fam       = 0;
    $first     = "";
    $first2    = "";

    $id        = array_rand($_SESSION['LAST'. $nat],1);
    $lastname  = $_SESSION['LAST'. $nat][$id];

    $gender    = rand(0,1);
    if($gender == 1) {
        $md    = array_rand($_SESSION['MALE'. $nat],1);
        $first = $_SESSION['MALE'. $nat][$md];
        $sec   = rand(1,8); if($sec == 1) { 
            $m2 = array_rand($_SESSION['MALE'. $nat],1); $first2 = $_SESSION['MALE'. $nat][$m2]; 
        }
        $gend  = "MALE"; $comp = "FEMALE"; $age = rand(18,80);
    } else {
        $fd    = array_rand($_SESSION['FEMALE'. $nat],1);
        $first = $_SESSION['FEMALE'. $nat][$fd];
        $sec   = rand(1,8); if($sec == 1) { 
            $f2 = array_rand($_SESSION['FEMALE'. $nat],1); $first2 = $_SESSION['FEMALE'. $nat][$f2]; 
        } 
        $gend  = "FEMALE"; $comp = "MALE"; $age = rand(17,80);
    }
    
    $fam       = rand(1,4);
    if($fam   == 1) {
        
        $ag2       = rand(17,80); 
        $cmp       = array_rand($_SESSION[$comp . $nat],1);
        $companion = $_SESSION[$comp . $nat][$cmp];
        
        $manf .= "<br /><span style='color:yellow;'>". $person ." : ". $lastname .", ". $first ." ". $first2 ." &nbsp; ". $gend ." [". $age ."]"; 
        
        # $person++; # <-- MEMORY ERROR
        
        $manf .= "<br />". $person ." : ". $lastname .", ". $companion ." &nbsp; ". $comp ." [". $ag2 ."]</span>"; 
                    
    } else {    
        
        $manf .= "<br />". $person ." : ". $lastname .", ". $first ." ". $first2 ." &nbsp; ". $gend ." [". $age ."]";
        
    }
    
    if($person == $pax) break;
    
}
    
return $manf;
```

}

Comment: There's too many unknowns here. We don't know what $_SESSION contains, and what exactly it's doing. If you remove everything between `$gender` and `if($person == $pax)`, it's fine, so it's something on the inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing `$person` in the for loop and also possibly in the second `if` condition... but you're using `==` in your break comparison, so you're introducing the possibility of incrementing right past the value of `$pax`, missing your condition, and running an infinite loop. I'll wager you can just do this:

```
if ($person >= $pax) break;
```

Comment: Heck. Well spotted. :) Thanks.. I've been staring at this code for so long,.. too long.